# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required

Tags: java, spring-boot, cucumber

Cucumber File Is ::

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)public class runTest {}
```

SpringRunner File ::

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, properties = "spring.main.web-application-type=reactive",webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@WebAppConfiguration
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration
public abstract class SpringIntegrationTesting {}
```

Step Definition File ::

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "Cucumber.xml" })
@WebAppConfiguration
public class UserLoginSteps extends SpringIntegrationTesting {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext wac;
    private MockMvc mvc;
    private MvcResult result;
    @Inject
    public void init(WebApplicationContext context) {
        this.wac = context;
    }
    @Before
    public void before() throws Exception {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
    }
....}
```

The Error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WebApplicationContext is required
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.DefaultMockMvcBuilder.<init>(DefaultMockMvcBuilder.java:52)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(MockMvcBuilders.java:47)
    at com.credable.test.UserLoginSteps.before(UserLoginSteps.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils$1.call(Utils.java:34)
    at cucumber.runtime.Timeout.timeout(Timeout.java:13)
    at cucumber.runtime.Utils.invoke(Utils.java:30)
    at cucumber.runtime.java.JavaHookDefinition.execute(JavaHookDefinition.java:59)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHookIfTagsMatch(Runtime.java:222)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runHooks(Runtime.java:210)
    at cucumber.runtime.Runtime.runBeforeHooks(Runtime.java:200)
    at cucumber.runtime.model.CucumberScenario.run(CucumberScenario.java:44)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.ExecutionUnitRunner.run(ExecutionUnitRunner.java:91)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:63)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:18)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:70)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:89)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:40)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.run(Cucumber.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

In Automatic testing of the spring boot api using cucumber and SpringRunner using features file in which the start of the testing by run run test class using junit testing it crash and give the above error